# Openshift OKD with other Ports (Teamspeak)

Tags: openshift, teamspeak, okd

I need help in creating an Teamspeak-Pod on an Openshift (OKD 3.11).
My problem is after deploying the pod, I don´t know how I´m able to give Ports 9887, 10011 and 30033 for external access.

Only 8080, 8443 and 443 is reachable for webapplications from outside.

Do anyone know what I should do to give external acccess? I think I have to do something with firewalld and port-forwards. But I can´t find anything for this.

Thx, for your help...

Answer (score 0):

By default pods can only communicate within the cluster, so you won't be able to route external traffic to them.

One way to do this is to configure the service as a NodePort. That will map those ports to ports in the range of 30000-32767 across all of the nodes. For example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: teamspeak
  labels:
    name: teamspeak
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: 9887-tcp
    port: 9887
    nodePort: 31694
    protocol: TCP
  - name: 10011-tcp
    port: 10011
    nodePort: 30906
    protocol: TCP
  - name: 30033-tcp
    port: 30033
    nodePort: 32316
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    name: teamspeak
```

If you run, `oc edit service teamspeak`, or whatever your app's service is called, and change the type to NodePort, Openshift will automatically assign a port in the range mentioned above.

After your service is setup as a NodePort, you'll need to forward requests for those ports to the new ones that were assigned by Openshift (the 30000 - 32767 range ports), so instead of requests going to 9887, they go to 30036, in the case of our example.

Reference: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.6/dev_guide/expose_service/expose_internal_ip_nodeport.html

Alternatively, you can define the service as type `LoadBalancer`, which will not only expose your pods to external traffic, but also distribute requests among pods per your configuration. For example,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: egress-2 
spec:
  ports:
  - name: db
    port: 3306
  - name: additional-port
    port: 9887
  - name: another-one
    port: 10011
  loadBalancerIP:
  type: LoadBalancer 
  selector:
    name: mysql
```

Reference: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.4/dev_guide/expose_service/expose_internal_ip_load_balancer.html